# Why does `foo()` work here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5k10h27j/

Why does `foo()` get called when set as an argument to an undefined function?

```
function foo(){
    alert('huh??');   
}
jQuery('#container').on('change', 'input', function(e){
    console.log('change');  
}).blahblah(foo());
```

Comment: Code should be posted **here**.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it "work"? It is doing exactly that which is requested ..

Comment: `foo()` is called before the js engine throws the error associated with the non-existent function.

Answer (score 2):

The function is called before any attempt is made to locate the undefined function.

In an expression like

```
  objectReference.propertyName( arg1, arg2, arg3 )
```

the specification for the language stipulates that the arguments are evaluated *before* any test is made to determine whether the function reference is actually valid. Thus, your call to `foo()` in the argument list is evaluated, and only after its value is known is any test made to see whether the property reference is to a real function.

[Here is the relevant portion of the spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3) Step 3 is the evaluation of the arguments, and step 4 is the test to see if the thing the code says to call as a function is actually a function.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling it. `foo()`. You can pass functions without calling them as in `.blahblah(foo);`

Comment: Derp. I need a vacation.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define your blahblah function somewhere, and it must prototype jQuery in order to be used in chaining. Once you have defined your function with a callback argument, you can call it by passing the foo reference and not the function call.

```
$.fn.blahblah = function ( callback ) {
  callback();
  return this; // if you want to keep chaining
};

function foo () {
  alert( 'huh??' );
}

$( '#container' )
  .on( 'change', function () {
    console.log( 'change' );
  })
  .blahblah( foo );
  // in this case you can keep chaining since blahblah is returning 'this'.
```

Comment: I think the op meant to know why it alerts 'huh??' even though the function blahblah doesn't exist. Like `why` would alert in the following code: `window.yesIKnowThisDoesNotExistButAlerts(function(){alert('why');}())`